BTF missing from Raspberry Pi version of Ubuntu Server 24.04
I'm trying to use AF_XDP sockets in my software. This works fine on amd64 architecture but on the Raspberry-Pi my bpf and xdp-loader programs fail to load with errors:
BPF program load failed: invalid argument.
btf_vmlinux is malformed

The directory where vmlinux should reside (/sys/kernel/btf) is missing from the RPi version of Ubuntu which suggest that the kernel has not been built with BTF support (CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y).
BTF is compiled into the kernel for amd64.
So, was this an accident or intentional to build the latest RPi kernel without BTF?
If it is intentional, does this suggest that Ubuntu cannot be used on the RPi if you need to use XDP?

You are asking the wrong people I would assume. "So, was this an accident or intentional to build the latest RPi kernel without BTF?" Only the person that did this build could answer this as a fact. We could only guess. I suggest to file a bug report if you want to find out. In the meantime: would this fix it -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73210590/kernel-compilation-error-when-config-debug-info-btf-is-enabled ?
